# explode spark column containing list of dict in str format

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

How to convert this streaming dataframe in pyspark,

```
+--------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|           timestamp|offset|stringdecode(value, UTF-8)                    |
+--------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|2023-03-03 17:21:...|    10| "[{"num":55,"cor":32},{"num":14,"cor":54}]"  |
+--------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|2023-03-03 17:35:...|    11| "[{"num":55,"cor":98},{"num":32,"cor":77}]"  |
+--------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

into this

```
+--------------------+------+---+---+
|           timestamp|offset|num|cor|
+--------------------+------+---+---+
|2023-03-03 17:21:...|    10| 55| 32|
+--------------------+------+---+---+ 
|2023-03-03 17:21:...|    10| 14| 54|
+--------------------+------+---+---+ 
|2023-03-03 17:35:...|    11| 55| 98|
+--------------------+------+---+---+ 
|2023-03-03 17:35:...|    11| 32| 77|
+--------------------+------+---+---+
```

stackoverflow is asking me to add text to post my question, but i don't see any need for this, hence this paragraph to solve the issue

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried using explode function? https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html

Comment: yes but won't work as the input is in str format

Comment: well there is your problem, convert the data type into the type you need.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [from_json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json.html) and expand the column

This would work:

```
sch=ArrayType(StructType([
        StructField("num", IntegerType()),
        StructField("cor", IntegerType())
]))    

df1.withColumn("asArray", F.from_json("dict", sch))\
    .withColumn("asStruct", F.explode("asArray"))\
    .select(*[col for col in df1.schema.names if col!="dict"], "asStruct.*")\
    .show()
```

Input:

```
+-------------------+------+-----------------------------------------+
|timestamp          |offset|dict                                     |
+-------------------+------+-----------------------------------------+
|2023-03-03 00:00:00|10    |[{"num":55,"cor":32},{"num":14,"cor":54}]|
+-------------------+------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Schema:

```
root
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- offset: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dict: string (nullable = true)
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+------+---+---+
|          timestamp|offset|num|cor|
+-------------------+------+---+---+
|2023-03-03 00:00:00|    10| 55| 32|
|2023-03-03 00:00:00|    10| 14| 54|
+-------------------+------+---+---+
```

Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: thank you, i've already found how to do it, it's pretty much the same code, except that i needed to use from_json twice, as the initial message is a str object and not a list object